# multi-character parentheses in syntax table

Tags: elisp

I know that I can have multi-character comment delimiters, but how about multi-character parentheses, e.g. if I wanted to treat the character sequence "%{" as an opening parenthesis and "}%" as a closing one like this

%{

}%

Answer (score 2):

Emacs does not support this, see the info entry for [syntax tables](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Tables.html#Syntax-Tables).  Comments (and strings) have matching delimiters - but they also have corresponding ["generic"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table) syntax classes.  The parenthesis class doesn't have similar support.

So, you're stuck with only single character parentheses.